# Display Percentage in a Row in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I am trying to display the percentage of row instead of their actual value.

I tried going to Analysis > percentage of row but it displays 100% for every cell. Any idea?

```
Before
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you wanted to calculate the percentage row-wise checking Percentage option in Analysis should work but it may have not worked incase you have selected Percentage (Cell wise) .

For easier understanding create a Table Calculation and use the Edit Table Calculation to understand how the Calculation works.

**Table Calc --> Percent of Total --> Row-wise(Table- across)**

Adding a sample screenshot

[image]

Answer (score -2):

Right click on the column you want and go to format of the number and change it to custom and add whatever you want

or go to the dimension/parameter you want to show. and change the default numbering format to %